# JavaFX ChoiceBox in a MenuBar

Tags: java, javafx

I make an application with JavaFX.

I want to have a `ChoiceBox` in my top `MenuBar` to select the language.
I want to disable the blue surrounding when the language control is selected. How do I do this?

[image: image[1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Id` of the `Menu` that contains the `ChoiceBox` to `transparent` and use the following CSS:

```
#transparent:hover,
#transparent:focused,
#transparent:showing {
    -fx-background: transparent;
}
```

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to do this with `transparent` as a class yet.

---

### Example

Output:
[image]

Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Foo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");

        ChoiceBox<String> languageBox = new ChoiceBox<String>();
        languageBox.getItems().addAll("English", "Deutsch");

        Menu languageMenu = new Menu();
        languageMenu.setId("transparent");
        languageMenu.setGraphic(languageBox);

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu, languageMenu);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(menuBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("MCVE");
        stage.setWidth(640);
        stage.setHeight(480);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, should i create a .css hjust for the contextmenu or for the whole fxml?

Comment: @Mattizin I would create a CSS-File for the whole scene, but that's probably just a coding style.

Comment: how does the scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm()); works? i get it to work when the css is in the same package as the fxml, but not when it is under src/resources/css/...css

Comment: @Mattizin Try it with a leading slash: [`scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/resources/css/application.css").toExternalF‌​orm());`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)). If that also  doesn't work, try [`scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/css/application.css").toExternalF‌​orm());`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResource(java.lang.String)).